# Close DBCP connection on application exit

Tags: java, oracle, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

In out app we use `Apache DBCP` connector for `Oracle DB`. But **every 30 or 40 minutes we get connection size leak error.**

Is there any way to close all connections from pool before app is exit?
 e.g. write a method, which can get close event and in that method we can close connections safely.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql there is a way to provide a timeout for sleeping connections (connections not closed properly). This helps a lot in cases where connections leak due to application not closing the connections properly.

There should be an alternative for the same in oracle as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you terminate your app, all the connections are freed after some particullary short time like few seconds. But if your app dosn't handle the closing connections  it may not exit at all. You need to close any open connections after you use them in a `finally` block of try/catch statements.

if your app is a gui app, the JFrame will not exit by default, and not termiante your app.

try adding this invocation on your JFrame (if you use one) it will cause the app to exit permanently after you click the "X" to close the window;

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: I use connection.close statement in finally block. but after the app is terminated I see, that in oracle connections are not closed. even after few minutes.

Comment: and no, it's not a Swing or GUI app

Comment: Are you completly sure, that your app exited? Check it in a process  manager, that there is no running instance of your application.

Comment: To add a hook on the exit event of VM, you can use   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread hook)